# Display array from a value in the array

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, nsarray

So if I have a array that look like this:

```
var myArray = ["BMW", "Toyota", "Ford", "Lamborghini", "Ferrari", "Lada"]
```

I want to display the value inside the array after "Ford", so BMW, Toyota and Ford doesn't show up.. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Using a Swift slice, e.g:

```
myArray[3...myArray.count - 1]
```

Output

```
["Lamborghini", "Ferrari", "Lada"]
```

### Option 1

If you don't know the index of the `Ford` element, find it using the `indexOf` method:

```
if let index = myArray.indexOf("Ford") {
    let startIndex = index + 1
    let endIndex = myArray.count - 1
    let slice = myArray[startIndex...endIndex]
    let array = Array(slice)
    print(array)   // prints ["Lamborghini", "Ferrari", "Lada"]
}
```

### Option 2

As @leo Dabus pointed out, a much simpler method of getting the section you want from the array uses the `suffixFrom` method:

```
if let index = myArray.indexOf("Ford") {
    let slice = myArray.suffixFrom(index.successor())
    let array = Array(slice)
    print(array)  // prints ["Lamborghini", "Ferrari", "Lada"]
}
```

Comment: What if I do not know what number Ford is? Because it can be number 1, 2 and even 100.

Comment: `myArray.suffixFrom(index.successor())`

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

You can use `dropFirst`, it returns a subarray without the first N items:

```
let myArray = ["BMW", "Toyota", "Ford", "Lamborghini", "Ferrari", "Lada"]
let subArray = Array(myArray.dropFirst(3))  // ["Lamborghini", "Ferrari", "Lada"]
```

There's also `indexOf` to find the first item and then get the subarray from the index:

```
if let index = myArray.index(of: "Ford") {
    let subArray = Array(myArray.dropFirst(index.advanced(by: 1)))  // ["Lamborghini", "Ferrari", "Lada"]
}
```